# find the middle element in Lists and Arrays

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, data-structures

Could someone help me to solve this assignment please?

[image: Assignement3]

I would think that a) is i) and b) is ii, but I'm not sure

Comment: Please add the reasoning for choosing those answers, and what makes you doubt.

Answer (score 1):

I won't tell you the correct option of your assignment question directly but will explain what you missed. So now you can try to answer it yourself.
Let's start with basic definitions:

**LinkedList:**
A linked list is a linear collection of data elements whose order is not given by their physical placement in memory. They are present randomly in memory thus we need a link to find where next element is in our memory, thus the name linked list.

[image]

**Array:**
An array is a collection of items of same data type stored at contiguous memory locations. Thus all elements are stored together in memory of system.

[image]

**Comparing both now:**

Thus in array we can directly access any element if we know first elemnt. Thus in arrays any element can be accessed using `[]` brackets, `array[index]`.

But in linked list if we have first node it's very hard to tell where will be the next element unless we don't check the link present in current node.

So in array you can **directly access** `kth` element but in linked list to get `kth` element you will **have to traverse on all k elements**.

Hope it helps. You can comment still if you have more doubts.

*Image Reference: Gfg*